# Simple Regex Help

Tags: php, regex

How do I grab the email inside a string using Regex?

My string is as follows

```
"First Last <first.last@email.com>"
```

I want to grab "first.last@gmail.com" and store it somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=235338.0

Comment: You might want also to check here: >["How to Find or Validate an Email Address"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) on regular-expressions.info

Comment: You should consider using [`mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses`](http://php.net/mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses) if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[^<]*<([^>]*)>$
```

For the rest, see [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Answer (score 3):

Without Regex (and likely much faster):

```
$string = "First Last <first.last@email.com>";
echo substr($string, strpos($string, '<') +1, -1);
```

or

```
echo trim(strstr("First Last <first.last@email.com>", '<'), '<>');
```

will both give

```
first.last@email.com
```

If you need to validate the final outcome, use

```
filter_var($eMailString, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Comment: Though you'd have to add extra checks for non-matching input. Slight advantage for the regex here.

Comment: @Tomalak if there is no `<>` then the Regex (ex @shad's code) won't return anything either. At least with my 2nd example.

Comment: Not exactly, because if the sting is ill-formed "bla <<nonsense> bla" a well-crafted regex would still work correctly (i.e.: no match), while substr() or strstr() would fail silently.

Comment: @Tomalak Ah, I see. Yes, but you could still run it through `filter_var` to validate it, though in the UseCase of the OP it looks like he's getting valid eMails right from the start. Looks like he's parsing mail headers to me.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, I'll do something like:

```
preg_match('/<([^>]+)>/', "First Last <first.last@email.com>", $matches);
$email = $matches[1];
```

Check out [the official PHP documentation on preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).